# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath called over and over again on scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UICollectionView` in which each cell is populated asynchronously from Flickr.

In my scene I want 21 cells, my code produces this just fine. However, my code is calling Flickr again and again even after all 21 cells are populated in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. I looks at the Apple docs and I didn't see anywhere that states that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` should be continuously called upon scrolling.

I want each cell to be populated just once and then once completed `cellForItemAtIndexPath` shouldn't be called again.

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData

class ImagesCollectionViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var mapLat : Double!
    var mapLong : Double!
    let flickrApi = Flickr()
    var imageURLSet = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // set the location and zoom of the minimap
        let clLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapLat, longitude: mapLong)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2, longitudeDelta: 2)

        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: clLocation, span: span), animated: false)
        mapView.scrollEnabled = false

        getImages()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageURLSet.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("test") // <--- this prints over and over again on scrolling
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlickrImageCellViewController
        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
            let url = NSURL(string: self.imageURLSet[indexPath.row])
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
            let img = UIImage(data: data!)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                 cell.imageView.image = img
            })


        }

        // This is where the cells are being populated


        return cell
    }

    //Get images from the flickr API and store in array

    func getImages(){

        let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = ["method": Flickr.Consts.GEO_METHOD, "format" : Flickr.Consts.FORMAT, "api_key": Flickr.Consts.API_KEY, "lat" : mapLat, "long" : mapLong, "nojsoncallback" : "1", "per_page" : "21", "extras" : "url_m"]

        flickrApi.performGetRequest(parameters) { (data, error) in


            for record in data as! [AnyObject]{
                if(record["url_m"] != nil){
                    print("record")
                    print(record["url_m"] as! String)
                    print("end record")
                    self.imageURLSet.append(record["url_m"] as! String)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: The collection view only creates as many cells as can fit on screen at one time and reuses the cells that have scrolled off screen as new ones come in.  `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will get called every time a cell comes on screen.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths on your collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the UICollectionView reuses cells. Each time a cell is repurposed cellForItemAtIndexPath: is called. Obviously making a network call each time a cell is reused is not ideal.

The best way to accommodate cell reuse and network calls is to implement a cache. This can be something as simple as a dictionary where the keys are your index paths and the values are your Flickr images. `[NSIndexPath: UIImage]`

When cellForRowAtIndexPath is called:

1) Check your cache for an image using the indexPath as the key.

2) If there is a UIImage for that key, set it in your cell.

3) If there is no cached UIImage for that index path, make the network call. When it returns add the results to your cache and update the cell.

A note on your code:

Since cells are reused, it is possible your network call will return at a time your collection view cell is displaying a different object than the one for which the call was initiated. You should make some kind of check that the indexPath currently displayed by the cell is the correct one for the returned image. Failure to do so can result in you showing the wrong image for your given data.

Comment: Use SDWebImage class for downloading the image it automatically caches the image upon download